# Format exception unhandled: input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, class, converters

when ever i try to run my program the compiler brings me an error  `Input string was not in a correct format.`

my code:

```
public int number;
public int evenOrOdd()
        {
            if(number % 2 == 0)
            {
                return int.Parse(number+" is a even number");
            }
            else
            {
                return int.Parse(number + " is a oddnumber");
            }
        }
```

and

```
private void checkerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pali = new Palindrome() { number = int.Parse(checkerBox.Text) };
            checkerLabel.Text = pali.evenOrOdd().ToString();
        }
```

Comment: `return int.Parse(number+" is a even number");` is the problem. You are trying to parse string to number. You should return string from the method and use `return number+" is a even number"`

Comment: Please include the declaration for `number` in your code example, and tell us how you set it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya at return

Comment: int.Parse(number+" is a even number") is your problem. int.Parse method converts the argument to an int value. The string you have passed to Parse method cannot be converted to int.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a couple of problems:

One is simply a design/usage issue: you have a method called "evenOrOdd" that returns an int. It would make more sense if instead you had a method that was called "IsEven" (or "IsOdd") that returned a bool, or maybe one called "GetEvenOrOddMessage" that returned a string.

Another is that you are trying to convert a non-numeric string to an integer (your `int.Parse` method will fail with a non-numeric string value).

Presumably you want a method that returns a message string if the number is even or odd, so you don't need to try to cast anything to an int, but rather to a string.

So we can create a method that returns the message we want, give some numeric input:

```
public string GetEvenOrOddMessage()
{
    if (number % 2 == 0)
    {
        return (number + " is an even number");
    }
    else
    {
        return (number + " is an odd number");
    }
}
```

Now, to test if the string is indeed an integer, we can use `int.TryParse`, which returns true if the parse succeeds and sets an `out` parameter to the value.

```
private void checkerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int input;
    if (int.TryParse(checkerBox.Text, out input))
    {
        pali = new Palindrome() { number = input };
        checkerLabel.Text = pali.GetEvenOrOddMessage();
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something if the input string is not a number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse will throw the exception in question if the input string can't be converted to a number.

Instead you should use `int.TryParse`

```
int parsed = 0;
if (int.TryParse(checkerBox.Text, out parsed))
{
    pali = new Palindrome() { number = parsed};
} else {
    // show an error and exit the method.
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use **int.parse** parse only the data you want to convert.Take note that the return value of int.parse will be integer. So letters and characters will trigger the incorrect format. For example.
Correct - int.parse("2")
Incorrect - int.parse("2a")

public int number;

```
if(number % 2 == 0)
{
return int.Parse(number) + "is a even number";
}
else
{
return int.Parse(number) + "is a odd number";
}
```